# how to do conditional validation in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to validate a field called `student_id` in my rails app.

The previous requirement is that:
the field is mandatory and will be consist of 14 pure digits, so I put the following code into the students model file will satisfy my need:

```
 validates_presence_of :studnet_id
 validates_numericality_of :student_id, :only_integer => true
 validates_length_of       :student_id, :is => 14
```

buf if the requirement change to if the field exists it must consist of 14 pure digits, how can I implement the kind of conditional validation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you mean "the field may be blank, but if it has a value it should be 14 digits":

```
validates_numericality_of :student_id, :only_integer => true, :allow_blank => true
validates_length_of       :student_id, :is => 14, :allow_blank => true
```

Note the 'allow_blank'. Is that what you mean, or did I mis-interpret the question?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like **validates_format_of** is exactly what you need.  You can give it a *regular expression* that matches a string of 14 digits.

Comment: Would definitely agree with this if the field is a string - bit unclear from the question! I had assumed it was an int.

Answer (score 0):

For rails validation,there are some default validation options.One of them is `:allow_nil`.The `:allow_nil` defaulted value is `false`.In the `validates_length_of` the options `:allow_nil` means that Attribute may be nil; skip validation.

```
validates_numericality_of :student_id, :only_integer => true, :allow_blank => true
validates_length_of       :student_id, :is => 14, :allow_nil => true
```